# SCSS strange compilation of `:has`

Tags: sass

I have issue with compiling my SCSS file that contains `:has` selector.

The code:

```scss
div:has(> .svelte-select) {
    margin: 0.12345678900rem;
    padding-left: .25rem !important;
    padding-right: .25rem !important;
}
```

But the selector does not work because it gets compiled into this:

```css
div:has() > :global(.svelte-select) {
    margin: 0.123456789rem;
    padding-left: 0.25rem !important;
    padding-right: 0.25rem !important
}
```

Which clearly does not have exactly same meaning...

When I omit the `>` relative-selector, the style definition matches, but it also matches *all* parent divs that contain `.svelte-select` element, but I would like to target only closest parent div

**EDIT**:

I also come to observation that in the following snippet (already compiled css), the first block terminates the "workaround" with `.svelte-select-parent` class as it does not match, but the 2nd statement with only the `.svelte-select-parent` matches successfully.

```css
.sidebar-modal .svelte-select-parent,
.sidebar-modal div:has() > :global(.svelte-select) {
    --overflow-spacing: 5rem;
    padding-left: var(--overflow-spacing) !important;
    padding-right: var(--overflow-spacing) !important
}

.sidebar-modal .svelte-select-parent {
    --overflow-spacing: 5rem;
    padding-left: var(--overflow-spacing) !important;
    padding-right: var(--overflow-spacing) !important
}
```

Comment: I suppose you're using CSS modules? Your code compiles correctly when I try it on SassMeister.